# terminal is garbled after install oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

[image]

My terminal show `?` after i installed `oh-my-zsh`.
I searched on the internet, and i installed `powerline-fonts`. But it still shows `?`. Help me please.

BTW: Theme i'm using is `agnoster`

Comment: Font doesn't have glyph.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Thank you. I change the font from Menlo to Meslo LG M. And that's work for me. My `fonts` and `oh-my-zsh` is the newst.

Answer (score 1):

I change the font from Menlo to Meslo LG M. And that's work for me.

If some one still meet same problem with me. If you are using iTerm2 or another terminal emulator that has separate selections for "non-ASCII" fonts, make sure the "Non-ASCII Font" in your terminal profile is also set to a Powerline font.

See [#4091](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/4091), [#1096](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1906), [#4756](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4756), [#3713](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/3713)

Someone needs to write a FAQ on this. :D